# How to patch the OS under Red Hat satellite server

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I am using Red hat Satellite 6.7 version.

OS info:

`NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.8 (Maipo)"`

I Know how to patch systems using Red Hat Satellite server.

But I do not know how to patch the OS under Red Hat Satellite server.

This is my server config right now.

```
[root@satellite ~]# subscription-manager config
[server]
   hostname = [subscription.rhsm.redhat.com]
```

Assume my satellite server URL is `satellite.mycompany.com`

My first question do I need to register my satellite server to itself like below to patch ?

```
[root@satellite ~]# subscription-manager config
[server]
   hostname = [satellite.mycompany.com]
```

Second question if I run `yum update` in satellite server I am getting below warning.

```
WARNING: Excluding 10771 packages due to foreman-protector.
Use foreman-maintain packages install/update <package>
to safely install packages without restrictions.
Use foreman-maintain upgrade run for full upgrade.
```

After searching I found this:

> Previously, when using yum to update or install packages on the Satellite base operating system might also update the packages related to Red Hat Satellite and resulted in system inconsistency. With this release, Red Hat Satellite prevents users from installing and updating packages with yum.

So they gave the solution like this

```
satellite-maintain packages unlock
yum update
satellite-maintain packages lock
satellite-installer --upgrade
```

Is the above commands are proper ?

will `satellite-installer --upgrade` will upgrade satellite version also ?

I do not want to change satellite version , I just want to fix patches to base system.

Comment: You have indicated you know and don’t know how to do something so which one is it?

Comment: @Ramhound I can patch servers which is configured to get patches from my local satellite server (satellite.mycompany.com) by running "yum update" , But I don't know how to patch base OS of satellite server. While running "yum update" it's giving warning .If anyone explains how to update base OS of satellite server without affecting satellite server packages will be better.

Comment: Did you see [Chapter 7. Updating Satellite Server, Capsule Server, and Content Hosts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.2/html/installation_guide/updating_satellite_server_capsule_server_and_content_hosts)?

Comment: @harrymc yes but this is not I want. Reason is this will upgrade the satellite version also.  I don't want that.   I am looking something like this. https://www.reddit.com/r/redhat/comments/e2ia45/patching_satellite_server/ . It will be better someone explain properly. Whether this is the proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the manual section 11.5 Managing Packages on the Base Operating System of Satellite Server.

Typically your satellite server should be dedicated to satellite and all updates to OS packages should be managed with `satellite-maintain package update`. It's a packaged appliance this way.

But if you really really want to update via yum (say you have non-satellite packages installed) then you use the unlock and lock commands.

And no, `satellite-installer --upgrade` should not change the version number of your satellite installation. It is used to run checks for issues, to conform with the currently installed version, restart services etc. **But** you shouldn't run it by itself, use satellite-maintain packages update and let it take care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub project
 [RedHatSatellite /capsule-maintain](https://github.com/RedHatSatellite/capsule-maintain)
might be a solution.

Among others, it can do:

> - Target server(s) for Capsule installation/upgrade.
> - You can run install/upgrade/update on one or more capsule servers at one time.

This might give you the flexibility and precision that you are looking for.